# Error in Sentiment Analysis using R Package "Sentiment"

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I am working on Sentimental Analysis using R Package "Sentiment"

neg_words = scan("C:/Users/kothasan/Desktop/Sentiment Analysis/neg.words.txt", what='character', comment.char=';')

pos_words = scan("C:/Users/kothasan/Desktop/Sentiment Analysis/pos.words.txt", what='character', comment.char=';')

score.sentiment = function(sentences, pos.words, neg.words, .progress='none')

{

```
require(plyr);
require(stringr);
scores = laply(sentences, function(sentence, pos.words, neg.words) {
    sentence = gsub('[^A-z ]','', sentence)
    sentence = tolower(sentence);
    word.list = str_split(sentence, '\\s+');
    words = unlist(word.list);
    pos.matches = match(words, pos.words);
    neg.matches = match(words, neg.words);
    pos.matches = !is.na(pos.matches);
    neg.matches = !is.na(neg.matches);
    score = sum(pos.matches) - sum(neg.matches);
    return(score);
}, pos.words, neg.words, .progress=.progress );
scores.df = data.frame(score=scores, text=sentences);
return(scores.df);
```

}

Sample data consists of two rows:. "text" is a column name.

```
                          text
```

1.  I am comfortable with your services

2. Problems not getting resolved

## Function used:

analysis = score.sentiment(sample, pos_words, neg_words)

When I run the above function, I got the below warning with Output Score as 0,0 which is wrong:

Warning message:
In data.frame(score = scores, text = sentences) :
  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded

Output:

score                                     text

1. 0                 I am comfortable with your services
2. 0                 Problems not getting resolved

I am getting the correct score when I use only one row as the input.

Could someone please help me to resolve this?

Thanks,

Sandeep

Answer (score 1):

Can you check wether the text column where you want to perform senti analysis is an vector.
Example: if data set has 2 columns : number and text. You want to perform sentiment analysis on text. So before running the code make it to vector like sentences=dataset$text. Now use the sentences in the code.